# How to add a class to an "a href" element using PHP?

Tags: php, html, class, navigation

I am trying to add a "nav-active" class to a navigation element with PHP. Here is my code but is not adding the class. What can possibly be wrong?

Here is the bit of code I am trying to change, so my FAQ navigation item has "nav-active" class:

```
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" <?php if ($thisPage=="faq") 
echo "class=\" nav-active\""; ?> href="/faq">FAQ</a>
          </li>
```

Here is the full nav2.php code:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Ukryj Się</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Menu
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">O Projekcie</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" <?php if ($thisPage=="faq") 
echo "class=\" nav-active\""; ?> href="/faq">FAQ</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/blog">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/#signup">Kontakt</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/en/blog">&#127468;&#127463; English</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

EDIT: $thisPage is declared in the faq.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php $thisPage="faq"; ?>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="Wynajmij magiczny dom w lesie z prywatnym dostępem do jeziora, sauną, kominkiem. Pozbądź się ograniczeń, zyskaj niepowtarzalną energię wprost z natury. Uwolnij się od wielkomiejskiego pędu. Pobudź swoją kreatywność.">
  <meta name="author" content="">
```

Comment: where $thisPage is declare?

Comment: it is declared in the html pf the faq.php page:
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php $thisPage="faq"; ?>
<html lang="en">

<head>
```

Comment: You are adding a _second_ class attribute to the element. You need to add the class _name_ to the already existing attribute.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! It explains why it was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Begining of each php page:**

```php
<?php
$thisPage="faq"; //Pagename
?>
```

**Navar.php:**

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="/faq" class="nav-link <?php if($thisPage=='faq') echo 'nav-active"'; ?>">FAQ</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="/contact" class="nav-link <?php if($thisPage=='contact') echo 'nav-active"'; ?>">CONTACT</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The class attribute can only be applied once. So you could collect all classes and put them in like this:

```php
$classes = ['nav-link'];
if($thisPage == "faq") $classes[] = 'nav-active';
```

add as many as you like and then convert the array to a string, but separate with space.

```php
$classString = join(' ', $classes);
```

and output in your HTML

```php
<a class="<?=$classString?>" href="/faq">FAQ</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Markus! Now I read your explanation and understand what was wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

The class attribute can only be applied once. The shortest way is the ternary operator.

```php
<a class="<?='nav-link'.($thisPage==='faq'?' nav-active':'')?>" href="/faq">FAQ</a>
```